# Firefox adds a bit of padding that shouldn't be there. How can I get around that?

Tags: css, firefox

My homepage shows up just fine in Safari and Chrome, but in Firefox there's an extra bit of space between images. Any thoughts on how to get rid of that? This is the [website](http://www.ashleyhinck.com) I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

There is white horizontal stripe between the rows of images, because the images appear as inline content and they are rendered as if they were large letters – sitting on text baseline, and there is some empty space below a baseline to allow descenders.

There are various solutions; the simplest here is probably to add the CSS rule

```
img { display: block; }
```

which makes the images block elements that are not handled the way text is.

Comment: Yeah seems to solve it either adding it to 'img' or a the 'a.link'

Answer (score 1):

Images are inline elements, so if there's space in the source it will be rendered.  Try removing the whitespace:

```
<img /><img />

<!-- or -->

<img /><!--
--><img />
```

Or try one of many other techniques listed here:  http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Thanks so much. With all my links and div tags, there was certainly a handful of spaces between the image elements.

Thanks again for the help!